# NoErrorObjectAvailable Script error LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Onchange of combobox value  getting error in popUp
However ,backend functionality is working as expected

MarkUp

```
<template>
  <div class="picklist-container">
      <lightning-combobox name="picklist" label={label} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} options={options}
          onchange={handleChange}></lightning-combobox>
  </div>
</template>
```

HandlerOnchange

````
    @api label;
    @api placeholder;
    @api options;
    @api value;
    @api context;
   

    handleChange(event) {

        console.log('value sent ftom drop down',event.target.value+''+this.context);
      
        //show the selected value on UI
        this.value = event.target.value;
         //
        const eventPick = new CustomEvent('picklistchanged', {
            bubbles : true,
            composed : true,
            cancelable : true,
            detail: {
                data : {
                    value : event.target.value,
                    context : this.context
                }
            }
        })
        this.dispatchEvent(eventPick);

           ```
````

Comment: Do you have a valid event handler for your `onpicklistchanged`?

Comment: Yes ,it is available ```    picklistChanged(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      
        let dataRecieved = event.detail.data;
        let updatedItem = { Id: dataRecieved.context, Priority: dataRecieved.value }; //Rating to Priority 
        this.updateDraftValues(updatedItem);
        this.updateDataValues(updatedItem);
    }
  ```

Comment: Do you have `onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged}`, where you include the presented component?

Comment: handling the event in the grandParent component

Comment: And only your grandParent component has `onpicklistchanged={picklistChanged}` in the markup for the child element? And there is no reference to the event in the markup of the child, where the grandChild is included?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

`lightning:combobox` value in event handler is not accessed like this: `const changeValue = event.target.value;`

change to this: `const changeValue = event.detail.value;`

Also, the below answer is still. You will need to do this if you want to set the local `value`.

---

`this.value` is an `@api` annotated property - hence it's read only.

If you try to set it, you'll get an error.

Try using a getter/setter to set your `value`, and actually write it to an internal `_value` variable.

```
set value(value) {
  this._value = value;
}
get value(){
  return this._value;
}
```

Then you will be able to set `this._value` in your event handler.

Comment: Hi Casper ,thanks for your help .I removed the  "this.value = event.target.value" but issue still there .

Comment: Edited - there is another issue for you to fix